# Ruby Socket - Run method over socker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, socket.io

I'm new in Ruby socket. I have project in the server and I sat up socket in the server as following :

```
require 'socket'               
server = TCPServer.open(2000)    
loop {                           
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
  client.puts(Time.now.ctime)  
  client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
  client.close                 
 end
```

I would like to run one of my method in my project from client:

```
require 'socket'       

hostname = 'localhost'
port = 2000

s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)

while line = s.gets     
   puts line.chop       
   puts "hey"

   # call helloWorldMethod()
end

s.close
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'socket'               
server = TCPServer.open(2000)    
loop do                           
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
     client.puts(Time.now.ctime)  
     client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
     client.close                 
  end
end
```

I believe your solution is in the [TCPServer class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPServer.html)

I found this documentation about [ruby socket programming](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm)

> ## A Tiny Web Browser
>
> We can use the socket library to implement any Internet protocol. Here, for example, is a code to fetch the content of a web page

depending on your routing you may want to adapt the url, it chould be `www.yourwebsite.com/users`

```
require 'socket'

host = 'www.tutorialspoint.com'     # The web server
port = 80                           # Default HTTP port
path = "/index.htm"                 # The file we want
```

> This is the HTTP request we send to fetch a file

you may change your request in a HTTP `post` or `put` request

```
request = "GET #{path} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"

socket = TCPSocket.open(host,port)  # Connect to server
socket.print(request)               # Send request
response = socket.read              # Read complete response
# Split response at first blank line into headers and body
headers,body = response.split("\r\n\r\n", 2) 
print body                          # And display it
```

> To implement the similar web client, you can use a pre-built library like Net::HTTP for working with HTTP. Here is the code that does the equivalent of the previous code −

```
require 'net/http'                  # The library we need
host = 'www.tutorialspoint.com'     # The web server
path = '/index.htm'                 # The file we want 

http = Net::HTTP.new(host)          # Create a connection
headers, body = http.get(path)      # Request the file
if headers.code == "200"            # Check the status code   
   print body                        
else                                
   puts "#{headers.code} #{headers.message}" 
end
```